# Font whose glyphs all display as missing characters, might be named 'nosuchglyph'

Tags: unicode, fonts, webfonts

I could use a font that might be named 'nosuchglyph'. This could be used for testing a font on the web with a font stack specified something like

> style="font-family:'Some Font Regular', 'nosuchglyph'"

Every glyph would be an appropriate missing-character glyph. It could be minimally the same glyph for every single character -- something like a black rectangle or a rectangle outline with a '?' in the middle, or some similar image to convey that this glyph is missing.  More ideal would be a rectangle per Unicode character code with a tiny display of that character code, something like this ASCII art for, say, the character code U+4f4f:

> [4f4f]

Whatever it is, for any glyph missing in "Some Font Regular" (in this example) the glyph in the output would come from "nosuchglyph".

This is nice for testing in order to see for a given font, say, "Some Regular Font" as in the example, which characters are from that font and which are missing.  This is meant to ensure you do not get the normal substitution for missing characters, which would show the glyph from a font later in the stack or else from some default fallback font.

Comment: See [Fallback Font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallback_font)

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: fallback font would not be good for this, since it would generally show an acceptable version of the missing glyph, and it may not be obvious that the glyph is missing. This nosuchglyph font should make it obvious the glyph is missing.

Comment: A box with the codepoint in it is non-obvious? Did you read the whole article?

Comment: Oh sorry, totally did not read through. This Fallback Font is exactly what I'd like. Thank you.

Comment: The character in Q is `住` (U+4F4F,  *CJK Ideograph*)